# Вывод формы из ajax и отправка данных из нее

Tags: php, ajax, циклы

есть форма, при нажатии на кнопку данные отправляются на JS и там методом POST отправляются в php файл. php обрабатывает и выводит уже вторую форму, если туда написать что нибудь и нажать кнопку отправить то данные не отправляются. Почему? Для наглядности выкладываю код

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function result (data) {
    $(".information").html (data);
    }

    $(document).ready (function () {
    $(".btn").bind("click", function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax ({
            url: "test3.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: ({name: $(".name").val()}),
            dataType: "html",
            success: result
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="information">
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя" class="name">
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
if (!$_POST['name'] == NULL) {
$fam = $_POST['name'];
echo $fam;
echo '<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя" class="name">
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn">
</form>';
} else {echo 'Введи что нибудь';}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать $(".information").on("click", '.btn', function (event) { ..do something })

Так как вы используете динамические элементы, их нужно биндить к примеру, данным способом